# Difference in schema of deleted and inserted magic tables for row update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In my MS SQL table I have created a trigger(AFTER INSERT,UPDATE) , inside that I have checked the columns created for **Inserted** and **Deleted** tables.

But I am finding mismatch of columns in case of row update , in that case both temporary tables along with main table are having different number of columns inside them ( like main table contains 52 columns and inserted is having 49 columns and deleted is having only 47)

Note: these missing columns are not computed columns.

So wanted to know , in which case we can observe mismatch of columns (number wise) for these tables in case of update.

Comment: Nope - that is impossible. For more help, you will need to post your trigger code.

Comment: The number of columns must be equal. To do this, you must specify the names of the columns.

Comment: Impossible, please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

As most of the commenters rightly  mentioned that it is not possible, when checked in more details the difference between columns was not because of inserted or deleted table but rather way in which columns have been identified for checking purpose.

In my code I used **XML for path** , which was skipping multiple columns of inserted if value against them was null. But when handled with FOR XML PATH,TYPE it gave identical coulmns.